# Sort words based on length without using in-built methods in java/javascript

Tags: javascript, java

Usually this can be done using sort method in javascript like this:

```
var my_array = ['my','super','awesome','list','of','strings'];

my_array.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.length - b.length; //ASC, For Descending order use: b - a
});

console.log(my_array);
```

But how do I achieve the same without using methods such as `array.sort/collections.sort/compare/comparator` etc but only loops? Is it possible either in java/javascript?

Comment: Mixing up java and javascript is one of the surest ways to get downvoted to oblivion on SO.

Comment: If you say "without using methods", do you mean using a loop?

Comment: @JacquesMarais yes loops

Comment: What exactly would you say counts at a method or not?

Comment: @k.krol.27 I didn't get you

Comment: Search for sorting algorithms. Bubblesort is the easiest, implement it in javascript.

Comment: @wilusdaman I understand but sorting logic can be achieved in both the languages and also that's the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, sorting string array using for loops.

```js
var arrString = ['my','super','awesome','list','of','strings'];
var length = arrString.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < length; j++ ){
      if(arrString[i].length< arrString[j].length){
          [arrString[i],arrString[j]] = [arrString[j], arrString[i]];
      }
  }
}

console.log(arrString);
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your question instead of using the length method of Java, why don't you create a method in Java that will  count number of characters in a string and just call that method in place of inbuilt length method of java as you have called it in your sample code.

Comment: Java <> JavaScript.